# Detecting onClick event for clicking Printout button of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to detect when a user clicks the "Printout" link after using the print task in ArcGIS Javascript 3.14.  I have set up many custom options in my mapping application where I ended up using a "Prep Map" button to recreate the print widget based on the custom options.  Rather than the Print button resetting to the original state after clicking the Printout link, I would like to hide the print button so need to figure out how to use a function for a printout button click event in order to do so.  Below is the code I tried after using the HTML selector and thinking I could use the class ".esriPrintout" to get the click event but nothing happens.

```
function openPDF(){
    $('.esriPrintout').on('click', function(){
        console.log("PDF Opened");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my issue.  I used the event for the print task printer.on("print-complete", ...) to call a function for once the pdf is opened based on a one time click event for the printer div in which I had the printer div.  Each time I recreate the print task, I show the print div.  See code below...

```
printer.on('print-complete',function(){
    openPDF();
});

function openPDF(){     
    $('#printPane').one('click', function(){
        $('#printPane').hide();
    });
}
```